# Azure Function binding: get both EventData and strongly typed message

Tags: azure, f#, azure-functions

I have the following function definition.

Message type:

```
type MailboxItem = {
    CustomerID: int
    AssetID: int
}
```

Code:

```
let Run(item: MailboxItem, userNames: string, log: TraceWriter) =
     log.Verbose("F# function executing for " + item.AssetID.ToString())
```

And `function.json`:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventHubTrigger",
      "name": "item",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "eventhubpath",
      "connection": <connection>,
      "consumerGroup": "$Default"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "userNames",
      "path": "blobpath/{CustomerID}-{AssetID}",
      "connection": <connection>,
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

As you can see, I'm using properties of the incoming message to bind an input blob from Blob Storage.

Now, I need to extend my function to access some metadata of the incoming message via `EventData` class (e.g. sequence number). Is it possible to add `EventData` parameter but also keep the binding to properties of the message body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No not currently, unfortunately, though this is a common ask and something we're tracking in our repo [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1004) and will hopefully get to soon. Until we do, it is an either/or - you can bind to EventData or your custom POCO.